# Sharepoint 2010 - generate charts from list?

Tags: sharepoint

Say I have a list ( https://i.stack.imgur.com/KSdWQ.png ) in Sharepoint 2010 that's updated ~10x a day. 8 columns, things like "Asset" "Name" "Minutes", etc are entered. Is there an easy way to generate charts to show # of entries per week on an asset, number of minutes, etc.

basically I'd like to create excel-like charts in sharepoint. thoughts?

Comment: One way if you accept third party software is to use Camelot .NET Connector and MSChart or similar software, there are some examples using Crystal Reports here http://www.bendsoft.com/net-sharepoint-connector/examples/

Answer (score 0):

You can use JavaScript to get the data (with [SharepointPlus](http://aymkdn.github.io/SharepointPlus/) or [SPServices](http://spservices.codeplex.com/)) and then generate a chart (there are plenty of JavaScript charts libraries, or you can even use [Google Charts](https://developers.google.com/chart/?hl=fr) that is easy to use).